# How do I count vowels in a string using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to count the number of vowels in a string using recursion. Here is what I have so far:

```
int vowels(string str, int pos, int length)
{
    if (str.length() == 0)
    return 0;

    switch (str[pos])
    {
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
      case 'o':
      case 'u':
      case 'A':
      case 'E':
      case 'I':
      case 'O':
      case 'U':
        return 1 + vowels(str.substr(1), pos, length);
      default:
        return vowels(str.substr(1), pos, length);
    }
}

int main()
{
    string str;
    int len;

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin, str);
    cout << endl;

    len = static_cast<int>(str.length());

    cout << "Number of vowels in \"" << str << "\" = "
         << vowels(str, 0, len) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, I need to set pos to 0 only on the first time the vowels function is called without resetting it to 0 on subsequent recursive calls. Also, instead of using substrings, I need to increment pos before each recursive call of vowels(). Also, the base case should be when pos == length (when there are no more characters to check in the string).

Comment: If you want help with your homework, show a lot more work.

Comment: Your code looks unnecessarily complicated - you should be able to simplify this a lot.

Comment: This seems horribly inefficient. Was using recursion a requirement of an assignment?

Comment: Hint: use an auxiliary function to implement the recursion, then call it from `vowels` with appropriate initial conditions. Also, you should pass `string str` by const reference, to avoid horrible performance characteristics.

Comment: @Xarn The vowels function is my work.

Comment: @user3010694 It is not about whether the function is your work or not. It is about showing effort and own ideas, not just throwing piece of code at SO a hoping that someone will write the rest for you. You have written out the requirements, now implement them one by one. It is literally that simple.

Comment: Note: You are not utilizing pos (is stays constant)

Comment: @user3010694 if you are not _required_ to use recursion, then don't use it here. There is no point.

Comment: @Rook I am required to use recursion, though.

Comment: Who is making you use recursion?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you forgot to increment pos:

```
/* inside the vowels function switch statement */
return 1 + vowels(str.substr(1), pos+1, length);
    default:
return vowels(str.substr(1), pos+1, length);
```

Besides, if you change the end of recursion condition to "pos==str.length()" you won't be needing str.substr(...) at all. Also, pass std::string by const reference (it's a good habit), if you do skip substr(...).

Answer (score 0):

I would define the function the following way

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

std::string::size_type count_vowels( const std::string &s, 
                                     std::string::size_type pos, 
                                     std::string::size_type length )
{
   const char *vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";

   if ( s.length() <= pos || length == 0 ) return 0;

   return ( s[pos] && std::strchr( vowels, s[pos] ) != 0 ) + 
          count_vowels( s, pos + 1, length - 1 );
}
```

And  using your approach

```
#include <string>

std::string::size_type count_vowels( const std::string &s, 
                                     std::string::size_type pos, 
                                     std::string::size_type length )
{
    if ( s.length() <= pos || length == 0 ) return 0;

    std::string::size_type n = 0;

    switch ( s[pos] )
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'O':
        case 'U':
            ++n;
        default:
            return n + count_vowels( s, pos + 1, length - 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure whether this is meant seriously or is brilliant trolling.

Comment: Why the test ` s[pos]` (`s[pos] != 0`) ?

Comment: Why strchr and no find_first_of ?

Comment: @Dieter Lücking AFAIK strchr includes character '\0' in the search. So if the string contains '\0' then it will be found in the string literal.

Comment: @Xarn What is the problem?

Comment: @Dieter Lücking In my opinion strche is more effective than the algorithm.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well, some of the typos are fixed now, but incrementing pos AND decrementing length both at once just won't work. (You will meet halfway through the string and terminate prematurely) + this question really doesn't deserve an answer in its current state.

Comment: @Xarn It is interesting why won't the incrementing pos and decrementing length both at once work?

Comment: Well it could,  but you would have to change your base case. As it is, you are checking whether your pos is larger than the string (you already iterated over the whole thing) or whether length happens to be smaller or equal to pos. Assuming the obvious API/usage, you would call the function like this `count_wovels("heyooo", 0, 6)` and as you both decrement length a increment pos, you will end your recursion at `pos == 3` which is only half of the given string.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use recursion for this problem. There are times when it is sensible to use recursion when you're doing C++ development, but for general use the lack of [tail-call elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) represents a little bit of a performance bottleneck. Generally speaking, if a recursive process only calls itself once per invocation, you're probably better off using a loop. If a recusive process calls itself twice (eg. descending into the left and right branches of a tree-type data structure, or perhaps computing a fibonacci sequence), it *may* be easier to use a recursive function instead of a loop.

That said, this is clearly a homework assignment, and sensible software development practises have no place there.

Passing in `pos` and `length` as well as a `string` seems silly... C++ has already provided you with a nice general purpose tool to deal with iterating through a collection (and a string is just an iterable collection of characters after all) in the form of... Iterators!

Iterators effectively encapsulate the notion of 'position' within a container. `string::begin()` gets you an Iterator pointing to the beginning of the string, and `string::end()` gets you one pointed to the end. You can dereference a non-end iterator to get the character it points at (much like a pointer), and increment an iterator to advance it to the next element in the collection.

Here's an example which simply counts characters, but I'm sure you'll be able to adapt it to your needs.

```
template<class Iterator>
int count_characters(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    // if we're at the end of the string, there's nothing more to count
    if (begin == end)
        return 0;
    else // note the pre-increment here. post-increment won't work.
        return 1 + count_characters(++begin, end);
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
std::string foo = "a phrase, yay";
std::cout << count_characters(foo.begin(), foo.end());
```

By way of a bonus, it can be used on any other simple container... a `vector` or `set` of `char` would work just as well as a `string` here, because iterators provide a nice generic way to work with containers. This facility probably isn't of interest for this specific homework question, however.

One function, no need for wrappers or passing superfluous parameters around. Be cautious if you copypaste this into the work you hand in; if you don't understand `template` it'll be a sure sign of thoughtless plagiarism ;-)